# Convert a columns in Row into a comma separated list

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, column

I have this example :

[image]

And want to convert it to this comma separated as CSV like
this:

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: (1) Are you actually saying that you specifically want the text in Column A *not* to be quoted, while the others should be? (2) Will there always be exactly six columns?  If so, can you produce the desired results with string concatenation (e.g., using the `CONCATENATE` function or the `&` operator) and strings that contain commas and quotes? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: You could try to use [TEXTJOIN function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) to connecte string, and then save this workbook as a CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Do :

- Menu *File > SaveAs*
- Click "More options..."
- Select the CSV format
- Select folder and file-name
- Click Save.

Excel can also edit a CSV file, if you wish.